# Не получается десериализировать Json списка<Объектов>, получаемый с помощью retrofit

Tags: java, json, retrofit, gson

Вместо Имени и Фамилии во вью остается null, хотя json приходит корректный.

Вот что показывает okHttpClient, нормальный Json:

```
2021-03-23 09:25:11.552 9136-9362/space.rodionov.vkontaktecatcher I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"response":[{"first_name":"Alexey","id":100082006,"last_name":"Rodionov"},{"first_name":"Konstantin","id":5789363,"last_name":"Voronov"}]}
```

Вот тексты двух логов из метода в MainActivity:

```
2021-03-23 09:25:11.558 9136-9136/space.rodionov.vkontaktecatcher D/MainActivity: onResponse111: space.rodionov.vkontaktecatcher.ResultList@e1abc51
2021-03-23 09:25:11.558 9136-9136/space.rodionov.vkontaktecatcher D/MainActivity: onResponse222: [space.rodionov.vkontaktecatcher.Person@e690cb6, space.rodionov.vkontaktecatcher.Person@f5e0db7]
```

Сам метод в MainActivity:

```
private void getPerson4() {

    Call<ResultList> call = vkApi.getPersons4("lessej, id5789363", "5.62", "/* my key */");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResultList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResultList> call, Response<ResultList> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                textView.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse111: " + response.body());
            List<Person> personList = response.body().getPersonList();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse222: " + personList);
            String content = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++) {
                String name = personList.get(i).getFirstName();
                String lastName = personList.get(i).getLastName();
                content += (i + 1) + ". Name: " + name + ", last name: " + lastName + "\n\n";
            }

            textView.setText(content);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResultList> call, Throwable t) { textView.setText(t.getMessage()); }
    });
}
```

Api запрос:

```
@GET("method/users.get")
    Call<ResultList> getPersons4(
            @Query("user_ids") String id,
            @Query("v") String apiVersion,
            @Query("access_token") String accessToken
    );
```

Person.class:

```
public class Person {
    private Integer mId;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    //constructor, getters
}
```

ResultList.class:

```
public class ResultList {
    @SerializedName("response")
    List<Person> personList;
    public ResultList(List<Person> personList) {
        this.personList = personList;
    }
    //getter
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё таки разница есть:

```
last_name и first_name
```

и

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
```

Соответственно полям  надо добавить аннотации:

```
@SerializedName("first_name")
private String firstName;

@SerializedName("last_name")
private String lastName;
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в JSON имена полей `last_name`, `first_name` А в классе `firstName`, `lastName`. Логично, что поля не десериализуются. У них разные названия.

Укажите названия JSON полей в определении класса

````java
public class Person {
    private Integer mId;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int userId;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    private String lastName;
    //constructor, getters
}```
````